# Parsing JSON with back slashes in golang

Tags: json, go

I have a client sending smb user info as json object. The user has two backslashes - for example: **{"user":"AD.EXAMPLE\\stack", "password": "gamma"}**

I have a golang app that unmarshalls as below:

```
type smb_cred struct {
    User     string `json:"user"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}

var cred  smb_cred
err = json.Unmarshal(input, &cred)
```

After unmarshal, it strips off one backslash, so the resulting string contains only one slash. I am trying to split the string with slash separator to separate user and AD domain to pass onto cifs mounting as : **mount -t cifs   -o username=stack,password=gamma,domain=AD.EXAMPLE**.

How to split string with baskslash as separator?

----update with the fix----

`strings.Split(cred.User, "\\")` fixed my issue.

Comment: Those looks like back slashes.

Comment: JSON strings (like most things) use backslash as an escape character, so a string with double backslashes represents a string with a single backslash. It is working exactly as it is supposed to.

Comment: Also, in context, that appears to be an AD domain user, which is correctly domain, followed by single backslash, followed by the user name. So, again, it is working exactly as it should.

Comment: *resulting illegal string* What does that mean? A string with a backslash is not illegal.

Comment: @Adrian, I updated my post. I am trying to do cifs mounting, so I need to seperate AD domain and user.

Comment: "Because the string contains one backslash, I cannot separate" doesn't make sense. Just split the string on backslash.

Comment: `strings.Split(cred.User, "\\")` is the fix. Thanks @Adrian.

Answer (score 1):

Backslashes are the escape character in [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). The character after a backslash has special meaning.

- `\\` is a single `\`
- `\"` is a single `"`
- `\n` is a newline.
- `\u2603` is a [snowman `☃`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2603/index.htm).

So `"AD.EXAMPLE\\stack"` is the string `AD.EXAMPLE\stack`. That is correct JSON, Go is doing the correct thing by interpreting `\\` as `\`.

If you truly want `AD.EXAMPLE\\stack` you need to add another escaped `\`. `"AD.EXAMPLE\\\\stack"`.